# Usage of snmp4 SDN

Tags: snmp, sdn

How to configure and use SNMP(snmp4sdn) in SDN networks?
I am using mininet for topology and ODL(Open Day Light) as a controller.
3 Hosts and 3 Switches  linearly connected and ODL as controller.
I need to configure snmp4sdn in the topology.

Please help me in doing this.

Comment: did you check [this](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/SNMP4SDN:User_Guide) ?

Comment: Thanks Parham..
I will check and come back if any help required.